# What "party" items are worth getting during character creation?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, magic-items

Details on the formation of this question can be found in [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1405404#1405404).

During character creation you are allowed 3 "uncommon" items. What items are beneficial enough to the party as a whole to warrant using up one of these slots?

A "party-beneficial" item is hard to define without restricting the answers too much. What I'm looking for are items that affect the group as a whole inside or outside of combat. Not something that just increases your character's power.

A few examples:

- Battle Standard of Might: +1 to all damage rolls in the zone. This is a good in-combat party item.
- Exodus Knife: Creates a 4x4x4 extradimensional space for 8 hours to take an extended rest in. This is a good out-of-combat party item.
- Dust of Appearance: Encounter power to reveal invisible creatures. It benefits the party as a whole but only one person can use it each encounter. This is a *decent* party item.
- +6 Frost Hand Crossbow: The party may be better off with a frostcheese rogue, but it doesn't directly affect everyone. This is not a good party item.

**From your experiences, what "party" items are worth using up one of your item slots at character creation? Which ones have you made the most use out of?**

Comment: Note: I'm currently interested in heroic/paragon items but a summary of good party items of all levels would be fantastic.

Comment: technically, the battle standard of might, is also good for a zone based controller attack. (even without the party)

Comment: 4x4x4 is pretty cramped for a single person to lie down in, not to mention a party.

Comment: @Cthos: 20 feet by 20 feet by 20 feet?

Comment: @Cthos That measurement was in squares :)

Comment: @dpatchery D'oh. Pathfinder has me assuming feet.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few wondrous items that can be helpful:

`Bag of Holding` <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=550)</sup> Level 5 Uncommon - Reduces the load by up to 199lbs for endurance weak characters... Though it is level 5, it is given out in a treasure parcel at the end the new Red Box set's module (when the player reaches 2nd level.)

`Battle Standard of Healing`<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3272)</sup> Level 3 Uncommon - 
  Power (Encounter • Healing, Zone): Standard Action. When you plant the battle standard in your space or an adjacent square, it creates a zone of healing energy in a close burst 5. Whenever you or an ally spends a healing surge while in the zone, you and all allies in the zone regain 1 hit point.

This effect lasts until the end of the encounter or until the battle standard is removed from the ground. Any character in or adjacent to a battle standard’s square can remove it from the ground as a standard action.

`Chime of Awakening`<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3198)</sup> Level 4 Uncommon - Power (Daily): Standard Action. You set the chime of awakening to ring when a specific trigger occurs within 10 squares of it. Example triggers include the presence of anyone other than you and your allies, the light of the sun touching the area, or the appearance of a specific character or type of creature. The chime rings in the minds of you and all allies within 10 squares of it. You and affected allies are instantly awoken (if asleep) and alert.
The chime of awakening can be fooled by creatures in disguise. It makes active Perception checks with a +10 modifier.

Comment: I can attest to the utter cheese/utility of a battle standard of healing. In a nasty fight, it can bring multiple people above 0, healing far far far far beyond its weight in HP.

Comment: In my last session, we found 40,000 GP in gold and gems. After prodding the GM ruled that it weighed half as much as it would if it were pure gold - i.e. a total of 100 pounds EACH for four characters. And I was the only one with a Bag of Holding.

Answer (score 3):

Our DM is currently awarding items from the Heirlooms of Mazgorax set. They are a cool set if everyone in the party has one.

- [Keicha's Amulet](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6363) (9+, uncommon)
- [Symbol Of Gajz](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6376) (7+ uncommon)
- [Skaivani's Anklets](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6375)  (10 uncommon)
- [Rovikar's Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6372) (8 uncommon)
- [Matrakk's Lenses](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6370) (11 uncommon)

The level range is a bit broad for a starting party, but the benefits to having each member with an item from this set is pretty cool.